# Double compression on gziped sitemap on elastic beanstalk rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, gzip, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, sitemap

I have a rails application running on AWS elastic beanstalk. For sitemap generation I am using [this sitemap generator gem](https://github.com/kjvarga/sitemap_generator). The setup in my `sitemap.rb` file is really basic:

```
SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.default_host = ENV['SERVER_ROOT'] 
SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.create do
   add '/pages/help'
   add '/pages/packing'
   add '/pages/privacy'
   add '/pages/security'
   #...
end
```

The sitemap gets generated by a cron job. To deliver the sitemap I have added this rule in my `routes.rb`:

```
match '/sitemap.xml.gz', :to => proc {|env| [200, {}, [File.open(Rails.root.join('public', 'sitemap.xml.gz')).read]] }, via: :get
```

The file will be delivered to the browser but as it seems it is gzipped twice. Unpacking `sitemap.xml.gz` results in another `.gz` archive. Unpacking that will result in the correct `sitemap.xml` file.

Am I doing anything wrong? What is causing the second compression? How can I prevent it?

#### Edit

```
$ cat /etc/nginx/conf.d/webapp.conf 
upstream my_app {
  server unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name _ localhost; # need to listen to localhost for worker tier

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://my_app; # match the name of upstream directive which is defined above
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }

  location /assets {
    alias /var/app/current/public/assets;
    gzip_static on;
    gzip on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  location /public {
    alias /var/app/current/public;
    gzip_static on;
    gzip on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }
}
```

#### Edit 2

I should note that the compression is correct for my Vagrant development machine running just `puma` as a webserver. So it might indeed be the Nginx configuration.

Comment: what does your nginx conf file look like?

Comment: @miah added the config. the problem is probably the `gzip_static on` directive right?

Comment: Hmm, I am not so sure about that, you don't specify gzip directives in your main location directive. And you said you are serving it via the routes.rb file. Is the file actually double compressed in the server?

Comment: `file` says: `sitemap.xml.gz: gzip compressed data`. A simple `gunzip` results in plaintext of the data. So I guess yeah its actually only compressed once at that point.

Comment: What is the full url for hitting the sitemap?

Comment: Domain.com/sidemap.xml.gz

Comment: It shouldn't be going through either of the location directives that have gzip enabled ... have you removed the gzip directives to confirm that it is them?

Comment: @miah I disabled the `gzip` directive for both locations but it did not change the outcome unfortunately

Comment: Alright, what is in your /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

Comment: The bitter result of my analysis has been that a cached version of the file has been displayed by my browser. Apparently the generated file was corrupted once and I have a locally broken cache. I will analyse this further by testing the file from multiple machines/browsers and I will remove or lower caching for the file so the newest sidemap is delivered at any point. Sorry for this depressing solution and thank you for your help. If any more problems occur I will let you know. Add an answer asking me to check my browser and I'll mark it as correct ;)